# What is that strange light ball appearing during launch of Russian Burevestnik nuclear-powered cruised missile?

Tags: rockets

In [this](https://rg.ru/2019/02/16/ispytaniia-iadernoj-energoustanovki-rakety-burevestnik-proshli-uspeshno.html) video of the Russian [Burevestnik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9M730_Burevestnik) rocket launch (uses nuclear power)

1) What is that light spot moving backwards (contrary to the rocket trajectory, backwards towards the launch fixtures):

[image]
[image]

Is it just some optical illusion or something more fundamental and always present?

2) Why are the engineers at the missile factory wearing masks/respirators? Is it to protect themselves, or is an extra-clean atmosphere required at that installation facility?

Comment: This is also the Cruise Missile's starter motor. It if goes "nuclear ramjet" it wouldn't have a fiery tail like that. One would also want to err... stay safely away to avoid "direct shine". (How do you stop it btw? Eject the core over the ocean?).

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to rephrasee the question slightly to make it about a video of an "allegedly nuclear powered missile" launch. The question can be answered without discussing the premise that the missile is what it was claimed to be in the video. (A premise that is debatable given the known technological difficulties associated with such a missile.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) This is a lens flare (as uhoh notes) - a reflection of the bright light inside the lens of the camera. Essentially, it is an image of the bright rocket exhaust, mirrored at the center of the lens. That't why it's moving backwards.

2) The outfit of the workers seems to be quite standard for any (basic) clean-room environment to prevent any contamination of the environment with any bits and pieces of the human body (hair, pieces of skin, droplets of spit, bacteria..). More or less the same outfit is worn in any modern food processing plant.